# How to get product list related to other sale transaction count in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm a newbie in Laravel and working on a small e-commerce project. I need to get products list that related to transaction count in the transaction table. Below is my demo data.

tb_product:

```
product_id    product_name
    1             A
    2             B  
    3             C
```

tb_transaction:

```
transaction_id    product_id
    1                2
    2                1
    3                2
    4                2
    5                1
    6                3
```

From tb_transaction. I have sale list as below

```
B = 3sales, A =2sales, C=1sale
```

I need to generate Laravel eloquent result like `[{B...},{A...},{C...}]` (count from max to min). I had tried some from google but no luck. Appreciated for advice, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below query,

```
DB::table('tb_product')
->select('tb_product.product_id', 'tb_product.product_name', DB::raw("count('tb_transaction.product_id') as salesCount"))
->join('tb_transaction', 'tb_transaction.product_id', 'tb_product.product_id')
->orderBy('salesCount', 'DESC')
->groupBy('tb_product.product_id', 'tb_product.product_name')
->get()
```

Comment: Hi, tried your code but getting error ==>  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'kakai.tb_product.product_name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `tb_product`.`product_id`, `tb_product`.`product_name`, ....

Comment: see my edited code. I have added `product_name` in group by now.

Comment: Dear Sandeep Sudhakaran, It's work. Btw, Can I use 'select *' instead individual column selection?. Thanks.

Comment: no, you can't. because we are using aggregate functions, and group by. when you are using *, this will not give your result.

Comment: Dear Sandeep Sudhakaran, Thanks. Your answer is enough.